# NDSolve error: Input is not an ordinary differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of DAEs. Here is an mwe:

```
tg = 10;

f[t_] = Exp[-(t - tg)^2/(2)]

Smat[t_] =  {{0, sx01[t] - I*sy01[t]}, {sx01[t] + I*sy01[t], 0}}

Dmat[t_?NumericQ] = MatrixExp[-I*Smat[t]]

HR[t_] =  {{0, (omx[t] - I*omy[t])/2}, { (omx[t] + I*omy[t])/2, 1.25}}

rhsmat = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}

$Assumptions = {Element[{t, tg, sx01, sy01, omx, omy}, Reals] }

eqn = {  ConjugateTranspose[Dmat'[t]] == -I*f[t]*rhsmat.ConjugateTranspose[Dmat[t]]/2 + I*ConjugateTranspose[Dmat[t]]. HR[t]};

bc = {Dmat[0] == IdentityMatrix[2], Dmat[tg] == IdentityMatrix[2],omx[0] == 0, omx[tg] == 0, omy[0] == 0, omy[tg] == 0};

s1 = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, { sx01, sy01, omx, omy}, {t, 0 , tg}]
```

I get the following error:

```
NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation. >>
```

Not sure what is the cause.

Comment: Notice the line `$Assumptions = {Element[{t, tg, sx01, sy01, omx, omy}, Reals] }` won't have any effect, because it only affects functions with `Assumptions` option.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the problems you had. Basically you need to use Thread to generate the equations. Also used ComplexExpand.

but NDSolve gives no solution to the resulting equations. See the messages it gives for possible fixes.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
tg=10;

f[t_]=Exp[-(t-tg)^2/(2)]

Smat[t_]={{0,sx01[t]-I*sy01[t]},{sx01[t]+I*sy01[t],0}}

Dmat[t_]=MatrixExp[-I*Smat[t]]

HR[t_]={{0,(omx[t]-I*omy[t])/2},{(omx[t]+I*omy[t])/2,125/100}}

rhsmat={{0,1},{1,0}}

eqn=ComplexExpand[Thread[Flatten/@(ConjugateTranspose[Dmat'[t]]==-I*f[t]*rhsmat.ConjugateTranspose[Dmat[t]]/2+I*ConjugateTranspose[Dmat[t]].HR[t])]];

bc = Thread[Flatten /@ (Dmat[0] == IdentityMatrix[2])]

s1=NDSolve[{eqn,bc},{sx01,sy01,omx,omy},{t,0,tg}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The most important part is removing `?NumericQ` actually :) .

Comment: So I made some modifications in the boundary conditions:  sx01[0] == 0, sy01[0] == 0,  sx01[tg] == 0,  sy01[tg] == 0, are absolutely crucial for me. I played around with boundary and initial conditions on omx and omy: omx[0] == 0, omy[0] == 0,  omx'[0] == 0,  omy'[0] == 0.1 etc. But I still get the error: NDSolve::bvdae: Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems. >> . Any idea how to get past this?