# NDSolve unable to solve DAE

Tags: differential-equations

Previously I asked [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287968/ndsolve-error-input-is-not-an-ordinary-differential-equation) question for a system of DAE and later found out that IDA solver works only with real variables. So I modified my system a bit and separated my equations into real and imaginary parts. So I now have 8 equations and 4 constraint equations in real variables. Here is the code:

```
Remove["Global`*"];

epsg0[t_] = amp*(Exp[-((t - (tg/2))/sigma)^2/2] - Exp[-(((tg/2))/sigma)^2/2])
ampsol = Solve[Integrate[epsg0[t], {t, 0, tg}] == Pi, amp];
omg[t_] = epsg0[t] /. ampsol[[1]]
tg = 10; sigma = tg/10;

$Assumptions = {Element[{t, tg, sz1, omg[t], omg[0], omx[t], omy[t], omx[0], omy[0]}, Reals], Element[{d00[t], d01[t], d10[t], d11[t], d00[0], d01[0], d10[0], d11[0], det[t], det[0]}, Complexes]}

rule = {Re[d00[t]] -> d00r[t], Im[d00[t]] -> d00i[t], Re[d01[t]] -> d01r[t], Im[d01[t]] -> d01i[t], Re[d10[t]] -> d10r[t], Im[d10[t]] -> d10i[t], Re[d11[t]] -> d11r[t], Im[d11[t]] -> d11i[t], Re[d00'[t]] -> d00r'[t], Im[d00'[t]] -> d00i'[t], Re[d01'[t]] -> d01r'[t], Im[d01'[t]] -> d01i'[t], Re[d10'[t]] -> d10r'[t], Im[d10'[t]] -> d10i'[t], Re[d11'[t]] -> d11r'[t], Im[d11'[t]] -> d11i'[t], Re[d00[0]] -> d00r[0], Im[d00[0]] -> d00i[0], Re[d01[0]] -> d01r[0], Im[d01[0]] -> d01i[0], Re[d10[0]] -> d10r[0], Im[d10[0]] -> d10i[0], Re[d11[0]] -> d11r[0], Im[d11[0]] -> d11i[0],  Re[d00'[0]] -> d00r'[0], Im[d00'[0]] -> d00i'[0], Re[d01'[0]] -> d01r'[0], Im[d01'[0]] -> d01i'[0], Re[d10'[0]] -> d10r'[0], Im[d10'[0]] -> d10i'[0], Re[d11'[0]] -> d11r'[0], Im[d11'[0]] -> d11i'[0],  Re[det[t]] -> detr[t], Im[det[t]] -> deti[t],   Re[det[0]] -> detr[0], Im[det[0]] -> deti[0]}


Dmat[t_] = {{d00[t], d01[t]}, {d10[t], d11[t]}};
HR[t_] =  {{0, (omx[t] - I*omy[t])/2}, { (omx[t] + I*omy[t])/2, det[t]}};

rhs1 = Simplify[Re[ComplexExpand[ I*omg[t]*Dmat[t].PauliMatrix[1]/2 - I* HR[t].Dmat[t], {d00[t], d01[t], d10[t], d11[t], det[t]} ]]]

rhs2 = Simplify[Im[ComplexExpand[I*omg[t]*Dmat[t].PauliMatrix[1]/2 - I* HR[t].Dmat[t], {d00[t], d01[t], d10[t], d11[t], det[t]} ]]]

eqn1 = Thread[Flatten /@ (Re[Dmat'[t]] == rhs1)]
eqn2 = Thread[Flatten /@ (Im[Dmat'[t]] == rhs2)]

eqn1m = eqn1 //. rule
eqn2m = eqn2 //. rule

lhs1 = Simplify[Re[ComplexExpand[ConjugateTranspose[Dmat[t]].Dmat[t], {d00[t], d01[t], d10[t], d11[t]}]]] //. rule
lhs2 = Simplify[Im[ComplexExpand[ConjugateTranspose[Dmat[t]].Dmat[t], {d00[t], d01[t], d10[t], d11[t]}]]] //. rule

cons1 = Delete[ Thread[Flatten /@ (lhs1 == IdentityMatrix[2])], 2]
cons2 = Thread[Flatten /@ (lhs2 == 0*IdentityMatrix[2])][[2]]

bc0dr = Thread[Flatten /@ (Re[Dmat[0]] == IdentityMatrix[2])] //.rule
bc0di = Thread[Flatten /@ (Im[Dmat[0]] == 0*IdentityMatrix[2])] //.rule

bc0omx =  omx[0] == 0;
bc0omy = omy[0] == 0;

bc0detr =  Re[det[0]] == 0.01 //. rule
bc0deti =  Im[det[0]] == 0 //. rule

rhs01 = Simplify[Re[ComplexExpand[I*omg[0]*Dmat[0].PauliMatrix[1]/2 - I* HR[0].Dmat[0], {d00[0], d01[0], d10[0], d11[0], det[0]} ]]]
rhs02 = Simplify[Im[ComplexExpand[I*omg[0]*Dmat[0].PauliMatrix[1]/2 - I* HR[0].Dmat[0], {d00[0], d01[0], d10[0], d11[0], det[0]} ]]]

ic1 =   Thread[Flatten /@ (Re[Dmat'[0]] == rhs01)] //. rule
ic2 =   Thread[Flatten /@ (Im[Dmat'[0]] == rhs02)] //. rule

sol = NDSolve[{eqn1m, eqn2m, cons1, cons2, bc0dr, bc0di, bc0omx, bc0omy, bc0detr, bc0deti, ic1, ic2}, { d00r, d00i, d01r, d01i, d10r, d10i, d11r, d11i, omx, omy, detr, deti}, {t, 0, tg}]
```

I get the following error:

```
NDSolve::index: The DAE solver failed at t = 0.`. The solver is intended for index 1 DAE systems and structural analysis indicates that the DAE index is 2. The option Method->{"IndexReduction"->Automatic} may be used to reduce the index of the system. >>
```

Following [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html) documentation, I tried several options for Index reduction and equation simplification. But all of them fail. For example using :

```
Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> "Pantelides", "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
```

result in:

```
NDSolve::indexss: The DAE solver failed at t = 0.`. The solver is intended for index 1 DAE systems and structural analysis indicates that the DAE is structurally singular. >>
```

I also followed [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) documentation to try this step by step procedure, e.g.:

```
state = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eqn1m, eqn2m, cons1, cons2, bc0dr, bc0di, 
bc0omx, bc0omy, bc0detr, bc0deti, ic1, ic2}, { d00r, d00i, d01r, 
d01i, d10r, d10i, d11r, d11i, omx, omy, detr, deti}, {t}, Method -> {"EquationSimplificatiion" -> "Residual"}]
```

gives the error:

```
NDSolve`ProcessEquations::bdstyp: Solution stage EquationSimplificatiion in {EquationSimplificatiion->Residual} is not one of {TimeIntegration,BoundaryValues,DiscontinuityProcessing,EquationSimplification,IndexReduction,DAEInitialization,PDEDiscretization,ParametricCaching,ParametricSensitivity}.
First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[$Failed]. >>
```

Is there a way to get out of this mess or is something fundamentally wrong in this set of equations?